# Turn off java.util.logging for a specific package programmatically

Tags: java, logging, cxf

I am using an SDK that uses [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) internally. Apache CXF uses the `java.util.logging` package for logging by default.

I want to change the logging level from `INFO` to `WARNING` or turn it off completely. Can I do this programmatically in the main method of my application?

Comment: Have you tried this [example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/gcbkk/index.html) ?

Comment: @eparvan I tried: Logger.getLogger("org.apache.cxf").setLevel(Level.OFF) and it didn't help. The INFO level logs were still being displayed.

Comment: This link should help : http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/java-util-logging-programmatic-configuration

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande Sorry, it doesn't.

Comment: I have tried the example provided by eparvan and it works properly with CXF3.1.6 and java1.8. I wrote an alternative with log4j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do this programatically, but it's not intuitive. Changing to SLF4J or Log4J may be better if you end up needing control at a a finer level or over multiple classes

The issue is that Loggers are cached using WeakReferences. From the time you call `Logger.setLevel()` until the Logger is actually used, it may be GC'ed. So, the Logger that logs isn't the Logger you set the level on! This is especially true in frameworks where there is a lot of GC at startup.

The solution is to programatically set the *configuration*, not the actual Loggers.

```
String logConfig = ".level=" + java.util.logging.Level.INFO + '\n';
logConfig += "handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler\n";
// ensure ConsoleHandler does not filter
logConfig += "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler" + ".level=" + java.util.logging.Level.FINEST + '\n';

//set your custom levels
logConfig += "org.apache.cxf" + ".level=" + java.util.logging.Level.WARNING + "\n";

try {
  java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(logConfig.getBytes("UTF-8")));
  // no need to close ByteArrayInputStream -- it is a no-op
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.err.println("cannot fully configure logging");
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note there are a few issues with this approach:

1. You are overwriting the built-in configuration, so you have to set the root handler. If you set `-Djava.util.logging.config.file`, it will also be overwritten.
2. Total hack - might not be maintainable or understandable later.
3. Your config string has to be valid. Note all lines have to end with `\n`.
4. Has to be called very early, preferably the first line in `main()`. If this is not possible, you may also need to iterate all the existing Loggers and update their config using `setLevel()` too.

Comment: `From the time you call Logger.setLevel() until the Logger is actually used, it may be GC'ed` That's not a problem if you hold a reference to the logger

Comment: Is there a way to have CXF use log4j programmatically without a command line parameter?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I think keeping a reference to the Logger should work, but that may require a large number of them if you are trying to keep different settings for different classes / packages.

Answer (score 1):

The link below from Apache CXF has a well understood documentation whether it's **java.util.logging** or **log4j** or **sl4j**:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html

It would be very easy if you are using log4j.

You can configure log4j for Apache CXF and then append something like as follows in **log4j.properties** file which will turn off apache cxf logging.

```
log4j.apache.cxf = WARN
```

Comment: Is there a way to have CXF use log4j programmatically without a command line parameter?

Comment: As @pedrofb suggested in you one of the answers. There is already a SO post available to set it programmatically - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965946/configuring-log4j-loggers-programmatically/9003191#9003191

Answer (score 1):

### Configuring logging levels

In the `/etc` folder of the CXF distribution there is a sample Java SE `logging.properties` file you can use to configure logging. For example, if you want to change the console logging level from `WARNING` to `FINE`, you need to update two properties in this `logging.properties` file as below:

```
.level= FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
```

**N.B: If you want to change `FINE` to other LEVEL, just change `FINE` to others**

Once this is done, you will need to set the **-Djava.util.logging.config.file** property to the location of the `logging.properties` file. As an example, the Ant target below has this property set:

```
<target name="runClient">
   <java classname="client.WSClient" fork="true">         
      <classpath>
         <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
         <fileset dir="${env.CXF_HOME}/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
         </fileset>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/myclientapp/logging.properties"/>
   </java>
</target>
```

Alternatively, for SOAP clients, you can modify the Java-wide `logging.properties` file in the `JDK_HOME/jre/lib` folder, or for servlet-hosted web service providers, placing a `logging.properties` file in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder (see [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html) for more details.)

### Resource Link:

1. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html

### [Enables/Disable CXF Logging (payload)](http://meetrohan.blogspot.com/2011/11/enablesdisable-cxf-logging-payload.html)

> To remove cxf logging just comment out or remove code the following
>   code from your cxf configuration xml file.
>
> ```
> <cxf:bus>
>       <cxf:features>
>           <cxf:logging></cxf:logging>
>       </cxf:features>
> </cxf:bus>
> ```

### Turn off extra logging:

To turn off extra logging, change the `org.apache.cxf` Logger level to `ERROR`. Add this line to `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=ERROR
```

### Resource Link:

[How can I turn off extra logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072515/how-can-i-turn-off-extra-logging?rq=1)

Comment: I am familiar with everything you posted here. Please read my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Log4j** instead of **java.util.logging** as is [documented](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html). This is a 100% programmatic way to configure a Log4j appender for apache CXF based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003191/6371459)

```
//equivalent to -Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger     
System.setProperty("org.apache.cxf.Logger","org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger");

//Creates the file appender
FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
fa.setName("FileLogger");
fa.setFile("mylog.log");
fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
fa.setThreshold(Level.WARN);
fa.setAppend(true);
fa.activateOptions();

//Add the appender to CXF logger
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.cxf").addAppender(fa);
```

You will need **log4j.jar** in the classpath and execute the code **before** any CXF initialization