# Disabling undertow logging

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, undertow

I have an app that uses various dependencies. These dependencies all use a tangled mess of logging frameworks. Since I do not want any library to ever do any kind of logging I have a small routine that attempts to disable it all.
This has worked well for a while, but recently for reasons passing understanding it has stopped working for Undertow. Now when the app starts up it prints this:

```
13:35:14.001 WARN  UT005060: Predicate max-content-size[5] uses old style square braces to define predicates, which will be removed in a future release. predicate[value] should be changed to predicate(value) - undertow.parseExpression 
13:35:14.046 INFO  XNIO version 3.3.8.Final - xnio.<clinit> 
13:35:14.059 INFO  XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.8.Final - nio.<clinit>
```

The code I use to disable logging is as follows:

```
static {
    // disables java.util.logging
    java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
    // disables log4j
    org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
    System.setProperty("org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level", org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF.toString());
    // Disables spymemcached
    System.setProperty("net.spy.log.LoggerImpl", "net.spy.memcached.compat.log.SunLogger");
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("net.spy.memcached").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    // slf4j has been disabled using the nop-logger in the dependencies
}
```

Google wasn't much help. I found a post [Turn off java.util.logging for a specific package programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461313/turn-off-java-util-logging-for-a-specific-package-programmatically) and attempted to use it but got nowhere. The spurious XNIO messages still pop up.

I want to disable all logging frameworks programmatically, I specifically do not want to pollute my codebase with config files all over the place.

Something I tried that didn't work:

```
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("org.xnio").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("org.jboss").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
org.apache.log4j.LogManager.shutdown();
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.jboss").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.xnio").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.jboss").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.xnio").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().removeAllAppenders();
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new NullAppender());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.findProvider()`. By setting a system property, you can override the default logger selection, e.g.
`System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");`