Java disable logging for a 3rd party package: CDKit org.openscience.cdk.renderer.elements.Bounds logger
I need to make some modifications to a program that uses CDKit to do some chemistry stuff. A method that uses org.openscience.cdk.renderer.* package and all it's children log a lot of warnings. I am not the creator of the original code, but needed to make some tiny modifications. I am struggling to disable the logger. I get 100-s of these messages:
org.openscience.cdk.renderer.elements.Bounds WARN: class org.openscience.cdk.renderer.elements.AtomSymbolElement not included in bounds calculation

I am not looking to fix the warning, rather disable the logger if possible.
I have tried various ways to disable the logger. From the first main method that the program gets triggered by, I tried to use java default logging manager:
Logger logger = logger.getLogger("org.openscience.cdk.renderer.elements.Bounds WARN")
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF)

Another thing I tried was this hack proposed in this thread, still all of the messages persist:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40549847/13153706
Trying to follow the CDkit docs, I tried to use their own logging tool, find the appropriate logger and disable it:
public class Simulate {
        
        private static ILoggingTool logger = LoggingToolFactory.createLoggingTool(org.openscience.cdk.renderer.elements.Bounds.class);
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            
                logger.setLevel(4);
                
   


To no avail also. I do not have the best understanding of logging, and it might be possible to use Log4J to disable it..? CDKit has surprisingly little examples etc available.

Can you make that code a minimal reproducible example please
