# Apache Cxf Interceptor

Tags: java, web-services, exception, cxf

I am using AbstractPhaseInterceptor(registered as InInterceptor) where i am validating the incoming SOAP Request before unmarshalling. If the validation fails, i ll generate a fault code and Falult info as response. I am able to get Fault Info but while throwing the exception, i get the below warning message. Can it be avoided?

My Interceptor

```
package de.jonashackt.tutorial;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

public class SoapInter extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SoapInter.class.getName());

    public SoapInter() {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message arg0) throws Fault {
            //throw new Fault(new NumberFormatException("error"));
        throw new Fault("Error", LOG);
    }

public void handleFault(Message arg0) {

super.handleFault(message);
XMLStreamWriter writer = (XMLStreamWriter)message.get("ORIGINAL_XML_WRITER");
if (writer != null)
{
message.setContent(XMLStreamWriter.class, writer);
}

}
```

}

This is my config file

```
package de.jonashackt.tutorial;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public Server  endpoint() {
        JaxWsServerFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
        factory.setAddress("/Hello");
        factory.setBus(bus);
        factory.setServiceBean(Arrays.<Object>asList(new HelloPortImpl()));
        factory.getInInterceptors().add(soap());
        return  factory.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractPhaseInterceptor<SoapMessage> soap() {
        return new SoapInter();
    }
}
```

> o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Interceptor for
>   {http://util.java/}ArrayListService has thrown exception, unwinding
>   now
>
> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Error   at
>   de.jonashackt.tutorial.SoapInter.handleMessage(SoapInter.java:22)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>   ~[cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>   [cxf-core-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]  at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
>   [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.10.jar:3.1.10]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]

What is the issue? Can it be avoided?

Comment: Try to swith off the logging. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072515/how-can-i-turn-off-extra-logging

Comment: @pedrofb Hi.. I have updated my config file too. Could you tell how to switch off loggine with an example

Answer (score 0):

CXF uses by default `java.util.logging` You need to configure the logging levels in your `logging.properties` to not show messages WARNING messages, or disable Console. See [CXF logging documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html)

For example define a `logging.properties` file with this content

```
.level = SEVERE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = SEVERE
```

And the following system property

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="path/to/your/logging.properties"
```

Comment: I tried using handleFault, still facing the same issue. please find the updated post

Comment: I have added logging.properties and changed the system property too. Still facing the same issue

Comment: I checked it, and the log configuration removes the warning message. Are you using java.util.logging?  Ensure the system property is correctly set, i had problem with it

Comment: Yes. i gave it as system.setProperty("Djava.util.logging.config.file", src/main/resource/logging.properties)

Comment: Remove "D". Also it is needed to use an absolute path for the file. Ensure the property is set before java.util.logging is initialized. If it does not work set it as a JVM parameter

Comment: Yes i removed and tested but facing the same issue

Comment: My code is similar to yours. I could not use `System.setProperty` because logging is initialized before the code is reached. I used JVM property (-D) at start of application server